# Can I set up secure boot on a PC without a TPM, Intel TXT, or UEFI?

Tags: security

On a PC that uses a standard legacy BIOS does there exist any software (a special bootloader) that will perform signature checks on the kernel (Windows or Linux)?

Comment: How useful is this? Someone could just replace the bootloader.

Comment: It is an interesting question from a technical standpoint.